# Groebner Basis for Functions

Tags: equation-solving, groebner-bases

We can use [*Reduce*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to solve the following

```
  Reduce[1 - Sqrt[a^(-1)] + Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(a + a^2)^(-1)] - Sqrt[2 - 2/(1 + a)] == -1 + Sqrt[2], a, Reals]
```

We can also do some manual calculations to derive a Groebner Basis and arrive at

$$256a^8-1024a^7-2080a^6+3520a^5+3105a^4-4060a^3+1158a^2-92a+1=0$$

We can find a solution using

```
  Reduce[256 a^8 - 1024 a^7 - 2080 a^6 + 3520 a^5 + 3105 a^4 -  4060 a^3 + 1158 a^2 - 92 a + 1 == 0 , {a}, Reals]
```

My question is, can you somehow coax [*GroebnerBasis*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html) to provide this eighth order result directly?

Comment: _because it does not allow for a single expression as an input_ ... yes it does, you can just put the equation in it: `Select[Solve[GroebnerBasis[eqn, a][[1]] == 0,  a], (eqn /. #) =!= False &]`

Comment: Now, where have I seen [this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773764/can-the-solution-to-this-equation-be-written-as-the-root-of-a-polynomial) before?  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Correct - that is the particular case for this this question, but I have come across it before. :-)

Comment: (For the record, I did try using Mathematica for that equation, but I only tried `Solve` rather than `Reduce`.)

Comment: I'd like to see if Groebner Basis can automatically derive that eighth order expression because the manual approach shown in the answer is cumbersome - although it does work. Anytime Solve fails, I automatically try Reduce.

Comment: @flinty: In that case, why not just use Reduce on the original? Is there anyway to get that eighth order equation (no radicals)? Based on your input, I did fix my misstatement!

Comment: Possibility 1 (gets close to the result): `In[204]:= g1 = 
 GroebnerBasis[
   1 - Sqrt[a^(-1)] + Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(a + a^2)^(-1)] - 
    Sqrt[2 - 2/(1 + a)] - (-1 + Sqrt[2]), a][[1]]

Out[204]= 17 + 12 Sqrt[2] - 174 a - 120 Sqrt[2] a + 225 a^2 + 
 44 Sqrt[2] a^2 - 192 a^3 + 240 Sqrt[2] a^3 + 736 a^4 + 
 576 Sqrt[2] a^4 - 512 a^5 - 768 Sqrt[2] a^5 + 256 a^6`

Comment: Possibility 2 (gets result, but as a factor of a larger polynomial): `In[211]:= g2 = 
 GroebnerBasis[{b^2 - 2, 
     1 - Sqrt[a^(-1)] + Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[(a + a^2)^(-1)] - 
       Sqrt[2 - 2/(1 + a)] - (-1 + Sqrt[2]) /. Sqrt[2] -> b}, a, 
    b][[1]] // Factor

Out[211]= (1 - 64 a - 32 a^2 + 256 a^4) (1 - 92 a + 1158 a^2 - 
   4060 a^3 + 3105 a^4 + 3520 a^5 - 2080 a^6 - 1024 a^7 + 256 a^8)`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Very nice! So much cleaner than the Maple approach.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Look at the two comments from Daniel Lichtblau.